# Go Web app on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk not showing output in logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is sort of an in-depth question, so I'll try to explain it as best I can.

I've built a small API service in Go that I'm trying to deploy to AWS using the relatively new AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker [support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_go.html).

Here's what I've done (the code is all open source, so you can follow along if you'd like):

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/rdegges/ipify-api.git
$ cd ipify-api
$ git fetch origin aws:aws
$ git checkout aws
$ eb init
$ eb create
$ eb deploy
```

This will use elastic beanstalk to create a new app (with docker), and deploy it.

If I then run `eb open`
to open my web app, I'll see my public IP address displayed (this is the correct behavior), so I know that my application is running / functional.

Now, in my source code, I've got several lines of debugging output:

```
fmt.Println("WOOOOOOOOOOOO")
```

The above statement just prints "WOO…" to the console. This is run every time a new request is made.

Unfortunately, when I run `eb logs` to view my instance logs, this debug line never shows up – and I can't figure out why.

I've tried printing to STDERR, printing to STDOUT, etc. – but I'm absolutely unable to get any output.

I've scoured the internet looking for solutions, but have yet to find any.

Comment: Can you post your `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `import "github.com/rdegges/ipify-api/api"` is being built from the copy on Github, not from the local copy. The most recent commit of the `api` package doesn't have the extraneous `fmt` statements. Also, the `log` statement in `main.go` works fine, as does the `fmt.Fprintf` already in the `api` package. Try to verify the `api` package is getting built from the source you think it is.

EDIT 6/1/2015:

All my tests indicate this is a problem stemming from having an internal subpackage, and the remote service having trouble with that. The `api` package is not getting built from the local copy. `fmt.Print` works just fine from `main.go`, and moving `GetIP` from the `api` package to the `main` package lets `fmt` print just fine to stdout during web requests.

Basically, all changes made to the local `api` subpackage are getting ignored.

The EB logs probably say something about which packages are being downloaded remotely; mine did.

I'm not a Godep pro, so maybe a Godep pro can elaborate. But FWIW, it seems like it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/134), tangentially. It might also be a problem with the remote service not building with `godep go build`, but like I said, I'm not a Godep pro, so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you are running an older version of the app, when I try to build the container locally I get the following error:

```
➜ docker build .
# Executing 3 build triggers
Trigger 0, COPY . /go/src/app
Step 0 : COPY . /go/src/app
Trigger 1, RUN go-wrapper download
Step 0 : RUN go-wrapper download
 ---> Running in c1854666d13c
+ exec go get -v -d
github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (download)
github.com/rdegges/ipify-api (download)
github.com/rs/cors (download)
Trigger 2, RUN go-wrapper install
Step 0 : RUN go-wrapper install
 ---> Running in 0bbdec1b99d7
+ exec go install -v
github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter
github.com/rdegges/ipify-api/models
github.com/rs/cors
github.com/rdegges/ipify-api/api
app
# app
./main.go:27: cannot use api.NotFound (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in assignment:
    func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
./main.go:28: cannot use api.MethodNotAllowed (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in assignment:
    func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Are there any errors in your event stream after you deploy? "eb events" i believe.